# Google Sheets / Excel - Sum column from separate sheet if criteria_range is valid

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets

I'm updating a personal budget spreadsheet to automate the relationships between my data.

The issue is my current attempts at solving this problem all return a blank value.

Here's what I'm currently trying:

```
=SUMIFS('Transactions - Month'!$E$2:$E$1000, 'Transactions - Month'!$D$2:$D$1000, "Taxes")
```

I'm pulling transaction values from the 'Transactions - Month' sheet (tab) to a "Budget" sheet (tab).

```
Transactions - Month'!$E$2:$E$1000` // **Transaction amounts**

Transactions - Month'!$D$2:$D$1000` // **Category name**
```

I'm expecting to add all **sum_range** values in the 'Transaction - Month' sheet that match the **criteria_range** values I'm calling.

i.e. C2 (Budget sheet cell) = SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range, criterion)

The result I'm currently seeing is:

```
"$    - "
```

**How would you solve this problem?**

Comment: I already researched a similar problem: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309525/excel-sum-column-if-condition-is-met-by-checking-other-column-in-same-table]

However, the proposed solutions didn't work.

My issue is similar, although not exactly the same.

Comment: There does not seem to be anything wrong with the formula.  Maybe make sure that there are no spaces or other unprintable characters in the data in column D that would make it so `Taxes` was not found.

Comment: I'm trying to trigger SUM to happen in the sum_range for any value that matches the criterion in the criteria_range.

For example: if "Taxes" appears in the D column in cells D2 and D12, I would want to add the values from the E column in cells E2 and E12 to my sum.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) for the help!

I was using invalid characters in the criteria_range cells.

**'&'** and **'('** and **')'** and **'-'** and **' '** all appear to be invalid characters.